# Duplication while concatenating regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, concatenation

I have a string, in which I am doing replace operation with the help of regex.It is done, in order to replace the particular character in the string, if that exists and to retain others.

```
var text = "abcdef";

var text = ((text.replace(/a/g, '1')) + (text.replace(/b/g, '2')) + (text.replace(/c/g, '3')));
```

Expected Output:
123def

But I am getting the output like this:
1bcdefa2cdefab3def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are concatenating the replace instead of chaining them.

```js
var text = "abcdef";

var text = text.replace(/a/g, '1').replace(/b/g, '2').replace(/c/g, '3');
console.log(text);
```

However the recommended way is to use a single replace for it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: @srikha you could do `var text = text.replace(/abc/g, '123')`

Comment: @srikha but if `abc` can occur at random places separately then use separate `replace()`